# Add multiple fields to multiple feature classes using ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, typeerror

I'm trying to add multiple fields to multiple feature classes using a list in ArcGIS Pro. This is my code

```
import arcpy
 
arcpy.env.workspace = "Tatjana\MasterGeodatabase\MasterGeodatabase.gdb"

FcList = ['Storm Control Valves', 'Storm Culverts', 'Storm Detention Areas', 'Storm Discharge Points', 'Storm Fittings', 'Storm Gravity Mains', 'Storm Inlets', 'Storm Manholes', 'Storm Network Structures', 'Storm Pressure Mains', 'Storm System Valves']

for fc in FcList:
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'CONDSCORE', 'FLOAT', 'Condition Score', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'CONDDATE', 'DATE', 'Condition Date', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'ESTSERVICELIFE', 'FLOAT', 'Est. Service Life', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'COST', 'FLOAT', 'Asset Cost', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'LIFECYCLESTS', 'TEXT', 'Lifecycle Status', 255, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'RESIDUALLIFE', 'FLOAT', 'Residual Life', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'ESTREPLCCOST', 'FLOAT', 'Est. Replacement Cost', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'ESTREPLCDATE', 'DATE', 'Est. Replacement Date', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, 'PCTSVCLIFEUSED', 'FLOAT', '% Service Life Consumed ', None, "", "")
```

When I run the code this is the error I'm getting

```
TypeError: AddFields() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

Comment: It should be `.addField˛`, not `.addFields`, see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm and https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-fields.htm.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `AddField` syntax. `AddFields` takes a feature class and single list of field descriptions as a parameter.  Either use `AddField` or convert your code to use `AddFields` syntax. E.g.

`AddField`:

```py
for fc in FcList:
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'CONDSCORE', 'FLOAT', 'Condition Score', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'CONDDATE', 'DATE', 'Condition Date', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'ESTSERVICELIFE', 'FLOAT', 'Est. Service Life', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'COST', 'FLOAT', 'Asset Cost', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'LIFECYCLESTS', 'TEXT', 'Lifecycle Status', 255, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'RESIDUALLIFE', 'FLOAT', 'Residual Life', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'ESTREPLCCOST', 'FLOAT', 'Est. Replacement Cost', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'ESTREPLCDATE', 'DATE', 'Est. Replacement Date', None, "", "")
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, 'PCTSVCLIFEUSED', 'FLOAT', '% Service Life Consumed ', None, "", "")
```

`AddFields`:

```py
for fc in FcList:
    arcpy.management.AddFields(fc, [
        ['CONDSCORE', 'FLOAT', 'Condition Score', None, "", ""],
        ['CONDDATE', 'DATE', 'Condition Date', None, "", ""],
        ['ESTSERVICELIFE', 'FLOAT', 'Est. Service Life', None, "", ""],
        ['COST', 'FLOAT', 'Asset Cost', None, "", ""],
        ['LIFECYCLESTS', 'TEXT', 'Lifecycle Status', 255, "", ""],
        ['RESIDUALLIFE', 'FLOAT', 'Residual Life', None, "", ""],
        ['ESTREPLCCOST', 'FLOAT', 'Est. Replacement Cost', None, "", ""],
        ['ESTREPLCDATE', 'DATE', 'Est. Replacement Date', None, "", ""],
        ['PCTSVCLIFEUSED', 'FLOAT', '% Service Life Consumed ', None, "", ""]])
```